# Integration of ibm watson conversation

Tags: ibm-watson, chatbot

I'm currently working on creating chatbots using ibm watson conversation. I have created my chatbot in bluemix with the necessary intents and dialog. NowI want to integrate it with a java application. Can anyone help me on this.?

Comment: Please provide a specific problem to your question, other than "Can anyone help me on this?"

Comment: sample code here: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/develop/conversation

Comment: I believe that link to SDK should be good for most of the cases. If you need to dig a bit more with details then take a look here as well https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?java#apiexplorer

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.conversation.v1.Conversation;
import com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.conversation.v1.model.*; 
public class Conversation {
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{

String input ="Hello";
//To Call Conversation Api to print its welcome Message.
response = conversationAPI("",context); 
context = response.getContext();
response = conversationAPI(input,context); 
}
}
catch (IOException e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static MessageResponse conversationAPI(String input,Context context)
{
Conversation service = new Conversation("");
service.setUsernameAndPassword("", ""); //
MessageOptions  newMessage = new MessageOptions.Builder().workspaceId("").input(new InputData.Builder(input).build()).context(context).build();
MessageResponse response = service.message(newMessage).execute();
int TextSize= response.getOutput().getText().size();
for(int x=0;x<TextSize;x++)
{

    System.out.println(response.getOutput().getText().get(x));
}

return response;
} 

}
```

Comment: I think this will be helpful. Put username pw and conversation id in code and version date.